# Unable to figure out datetime query in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hi Im unable to figure out whats wrong with my datetime query `=QUERY(A:G,"SELECT * WHERE G < datetime '2022-08-24 08:45:00'",1)` in my Google Sheet it should return 2 rows on the left whos datetimes in G are `< 2022-08-24 08:45:00` (also supplied screenshot) [image]

Comment: You query is correct. What result do you get?

Comment: No results heres a link to google sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qibY44cdAOz6-vvzfa8w33ano_T_lMuoJ-uEbfbwjso/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made changes to formula to your ***G column*** `=DATE(LEFT(B2,4),MID(B2,5,2),RIGHT(B2,2))+(TIME(C2,D2,0))` to make it pure datetime value. Then use below query formula.

```
=QUERY(A:G,"SELECT * WHERE G < datetime '2022-08-24 08:45:00'",1)
```

See your google sheet `harun24hr`.

Comment: Thanks @Harun24hr, really appreciate you help resolve my issue within the sheet wasnt sure what you meant by 'pure datetime value' but I assume thats what player0 meant about G shouldnt be a text string, so definitely upvoting there answer too

Comment: @experimenter When you are using text function then it will return value as text (formatted looks like data but they are not true date). Date() and TIME() function will return true datetime values as equivalent number, and then your can apply any date time format to that value to display it what you want. Also you can compare this datetime value with other date and time but you can not compare text() function output with other datetimes as they are not true date (they are only texts).

Answer (score 2):

should be:

```
=QUERY(A:G, "WHERE G < datetime '2022-08-24 08:45:00'", 1)
```

[image]

`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` is the correct format - https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#literals

and G2 cant be a text string so multiply it by 1:

```
=(TEXT(DATE(LEFT(B2,4),MID(B2,5,2),
 RIGHT(B2,2)),"yyyy-MM-dd")&" "&TEXT(TIME(C2,D2,0),"HH:mm:ss"))*1
```

but it's better if you use arrayformula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(DATE(LEFT(B2:B, 4), MID(B2:B, 5, 2), 
 RIGHT(B2:B, 2))+(TIME(C2:C, D2:D, ))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks heaps player0 your explanation was super helpful so Ive upvoted your as well

Answer (score 0):

### Suggestion:

Since the `QUERY()` function runs a Google Visualization API Query Language query across data it runs slower than the usual formulas in google sheets. This will be very noticeable if you have large data. So another way is using
the `FILTER()` function to filter only the date less than **'2022-08-24 08:45:00'**. This runs much faster, almost instantly. The only key difference here is you have to manually copy the headers and start on row 2.

**You first have to convert your Column G to an actual Date & Time Format using:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="", "", DATE(LEFT(B2:B,4),MID(B2:B,5,2),RIGHT(B2:B,2))+(TIME(C2:C,D2:D,0))))
```

[image]

---

**Then using Filter:**

```
=FILTER(A1:G, G1:G < DATE(2022,8,24)+time(8,45,0))
```

**Result:**

Headers manually copied.
[image]
**Just added some test data to see that the filter works.

**References:**

- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)
- [DATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092969?hl=en#:%7E:text=Google%20Sheets%20uses%20the%201900,of%202%2F1%2F2019.)
- [TIME](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093056?hl=en)
- [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)